# How to change a widget's color at runtime?

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the color of a widget using another class. But i can't find the layout that i'm trying to change,because this layout is in another xml file. The widget layout have a LinearLayout that uses a shape.xml as background. I've tried a lot of things,but nothing worked.

Here's the MyShape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<solid
android:color="#DDf5f5f5" />

<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

And this is what the class do when i click on the Change Collor button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myRoot = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_layout, myRoot);
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) linear.getBackground().mutate();
sd.setColor(picker.getColor());
}
```

The class WidgetColorPicker uses the layout "widget_color.xml" and the LinearLayout that i want to change is on the "widget_layout.xml".

Comment: I was able to do it using drawable color.                    GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_shape);
shape.setColor(mycolor);

Comment: I've tried it, but doesn't work too, the color still the same. but thanks anyway!